# Can I refuse to eat food from parents?

Tags: halal-haram

I have my own way of eating, and I only like to eat food that I prepared. Can I refuse food from others? even from parents?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. This seems to be more of a question on social behavior than Islam. You may need to [edit] the question to add more details (if registered).

Answer (score 1):

Bro it's not a big matter, you can refuse them but in a way so it should not hurt them. Better to prepare for yourself and for them as well.

Once you will grow up and will have children then you will realize it, how much parents care about their kids [I don't know your age, so sorry if you already have children]

Some verses from Quran:

Verse (2:83) To parents do good and to relatives, orphans, and the needy. And speak to people good [words] and establish prayer and give zakah."

Verse (33:70) O you who have believed, fear Allah and speak words of appropriate justice.